# How do I get the root directory of my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am able to access the temporary directory for the current user of my iOS app, and I am able to access the bundle path as the following code shows:

```
    print(FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory)

    print(Bundle.main.bundlePath)
```

How do I access the root directory of the app for the current user? I need to create a cache directory or a Documents directory according to the instructions in the documentation in this link:

(https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW13)

The beta version of Xcode provides for a property that gives access to the home directory, but the latest release of Xcode does not.

Answer (score 3):

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

let pathOfDir = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
print(pathOfDir)
```

This is use for get your root directory

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create a cache directory or a Documents directory according to the instructions in the documentation in this link:

You don't need to do this.

You access the Caches directory as follows:

```
try! FileManager.default.url(for: .cachesDirectory,
                                 in: .userDomainMask,
                                 appropriateFor: nil,
                                 create: false)
```

.. and the `documents` directory as directed above.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL 
{

  let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

  let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
return documentsDirectory

}
```

Please check this function for get root directory

Comment: FYI - This gives the Documents folder, not the root folder of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Swift :

```
let homeDirectoryString = NSHomeDirectory()
let homeDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: homeDirectoryString, isDirectory: true)
```

ObjC

```
NSString *homeDirectoryString = NSHomeDirectory();
NSURL *homeDirectoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:homeDirectoryString isDirectory:TRUE];
```